# Html input field not clear, used clear() but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created form in html using php, ajax, javascript, jquery. after entering data ,its updated in database but input field not been clear. i wright clear() in java script. but its not working please help me below is code

index.html

```html
<html>
<head><title>Registration form</title></head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="process.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"> <br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"> <br />
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"> <br />
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"> <br />

<button id="submit" name="submit">Register</button>
</form>

<div id="ack">Acknowledge</div> 

<script type="text/JavaScript" src="script/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="script/my_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my_script.js

```js
$("#submit").on('click',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $.post(
            $("#myForm").attr("action"),
            $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
            function(info,status,xhr){
                $("#ack").empty();
                $("#ack").html(info);
                clear();
            
   });

    $("#myForm").submit( function(){
    return false;
 } );
});

function clear(){
    $("#myForm:input").each(function(){
        $(this).val("");
    });
}
```

i need the text field become clear.

Comment: I'd move the logic in your `click` handler to the `submit` one instead, and don't return false. Simply keep the `e.preventDefault() at the top.

Comment: Change $("#myForm:input") to  $("#myForm :input")

Comment: [This](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-function-clear-form-data/) can help you.

Comment: what is `clear()`? There is no global clear method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well sometimes this is a problem I would refer you to the answer from **scaisEdge** But if you want to do it with jQuery I think you have to change this:

```
function clear(){
    $("#myForm:input").each(function(){
        $(this).val("");
    });
}
```

to that:

```
function clear(){
   $('form#myForm')[0].reset();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why not a simple

```
function clear(){
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
```

or after the submit if you prefer

```
$("#myForm").submit( function(){
   document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    return false;  
   } );
});
```

Comment: where to right document.getElementById("myForm").reset(); in above code

Comment: If the answer  provided by me and or by the other colleage are  useful you should rate it.. use the upper arrow near each answer. Andfor  the answer  you think is most usefule you can mark it as accepted ....

Answer (score 1):

For your code, update your selector would work (changed from #myForm:input to #myForm input or #myForm :input):

```
$("#myForm input").each(function () {
    // your code
})
```

But here is a simpler solution:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```